# Limit of c.d.f. of Poisson($n$) when $n$ goes to infinity

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, proof

I'm trying to prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_{X}(n)=1/2$ when $X\sim \text{Poisson}(n)$ without success.  Could someone help me ?

Comment: **Hint**: Use the CLT.

Comment: I thought I had to use incomplete gamma functions properties since $F_{X}(n)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1,n)}{n!}$.

Comment: I suppose you could do that, but one reason to consider my hint is that you will then see why an analogous result is true in *much* greater generality.

Comment: To add to cardinal's hint, $X = Y_1+Y_2+\cdots + Y_n$ where the $Y_i$ are independent Poisson$(1)$ random variables.

Answer (score 2):

You know that your variable $X_{n}$ takes a value between $0$ and $n$ with probability $Pr(X_{n}\leq n)$. If your random variables $Y_{n}$ are independent, then it holds that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}\sim X \sim Poi(n)$, hence
$$Pr \left(\frac{Y_{1} + Y_{2}+...+Y_{n} - n}{\sqrt{n}}\leq 0\right) = Pr\left(X_{n} \leq n \right)$$
If you then apply the central limit theorem to the left-hand side expression, you will see that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} Pr \left(\frac{Y_{1} + Y_{2}+...+Y_{n} - n}{\sqrt{n}}\leq 0\right)$$
converges in distribution towards a Normal distribution with $N(0,1)$ (check this). To get your answer, you then just have to see what is the probability that $P(N(0,1)) \leq 0)$